# Changing the Display Header in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Is there any way to remove the picture image or reduce the size of the displayed email header?  This take up too much space and I would prefer just a simple To/From header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce visual redundancies in Outlook 2013?](http://superuser.com/questions/518077/reduce-visual-redundancies-in-outlook-2013) Also see [OutLook 2013 Reading Pane screen real estate issue](http://superuser.com/questions/550853/outlook-2013-reading-pane-pain-screen-realestate-issue).

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time. Microsoft felt there was a bug in the "Hide Header" function and removed it.

[Microsoft Community - Remove the message header in the reading pane](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/remove-the-message-header-in-the-reading-pane/e3ce2ddf-6463-45ae-b8bb-ff8ff38aa2ff)