# Reduce/compact header feature missing in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

Even if [this MS blog](https://blogs.office.com/2014/03/12/compact-message-header-in-outlook-2013/) and [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/691649/86828) claim the huge message header can be reduced by clicking the arrow:

[image]

It does not work on my system. The arrow is not there:
[image]

My Outlook version is 15.0.4849.1000 (32 bit) running on Windows 7 64-bit.

How to get it back? Or is there another way to reduce the header?

Comment: Do you have KB2837618 installed? That is required for that option to work.

Comment: I believe that, unfortunately, the minimize button is only available for those who make use of the right side or bottom reading pane.  If you don't use a reading pane, and instead open each message in a separate window, you do not get the minimize option.

Comment: @harrymc I read that as well and tried it. I still had the twisty to collapse and expand even after a restart of Outlook.

Comment: Try turning off High DPI. Outlook 2016 also has that button the separate message window, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Workaround: hiding the entire header.

As [the other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1124813/287473) stated, this is not available in Message view. As a workaround, you can show/hide the entire message header by using **Actions** menu:

[image]

In many cases you know very well who the recipients are, what is the message subject etc. so completely hiding this information might not pose a big problem.

Using **Customize...** command (right-click the ribbon) you can add command for showing/hiding message header *directly to the ribbon* so you will be able to toggle the visibility quickly, without diving into the menu.

Answer (score 3):

One key information is apparently missing from both of your references:

That feature works only when you read the message only when you read the mail in the main window of Outlook (your first screenshot, `Reply, Reply All, Forward` links are visible), but not when you're reading it in it's own window (your second screenshot).

So your system works as expected.